# Rodeo IDE: unable to install new packages

Tags: python, ide, pip, rodeo

I've been using Rodeo for a few weeks as a better (IMO) alternative to Jupyter Notebooks. But, it has a huge problem: I can't download any packages that didn't already come with it - for example, Seaborn. Whenever I try to do this on my work laptop, Windows 7 generates a popup error "pip.exe has stopped working". On my home laptop (a much more powerful computer), Windows 10 doesn't even generate an error - it simply doesn't install the package. Note that I had no issues installing packages in Jupyter.

Also, please keep advice as least technical as possible - I'm not a coder, don't use the console or github, or any of that. I've just gotten into data science training in the last couple of years.

[image: Rodeo unable to install package]

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar issue, I have Anaconda3 installed and wanted to use Rodeo.

Finally this solved it:
-install anaconda
-in anaconda run "! pip install rodeo" (this opened a folder with rodeo.exe, ignore it, let it be)
 - install rodeo with exe from the web

Then when I open the rodeo app (the one installed from exe not from anaconda), installing packages works. No idea why, but after a day of trying this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue. After some findings, i found out that it's due to the antivirus setting. I am using 360 antivirus and what i have done is to add the Rodeo and Python folders into trusted folder and everything run fine now for my Rodeo.